# Geometric description of the domain of a function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> A real function f of two real variables is given by $$f(x,y)=\sqrt{4 \sqrt{3}y-13x^2-7y^2-6 \sqrt{3}xy-4x}$$ **Give a thorough geometric descrition of the domain of f using terms as open, ended, finite, infinite limited, connected and non conncted.**
>   Note: The terms have been directly translated and might not be the exact appropriate translation for for mathematics. Original language is Danish where Open: Åben, Ended: Afsluttet, Finite: Begrænset, infinite: Ubegrænset, Connected: Sammenhængene Non connected: Ikke-sammenhængene

How can this question be approached?

Comment: @DavidQuinn Thanks for noticing. I corrected it now - It should have been a "y"

Comment: coherent and non coherent are not math terms I am familiar with. Also should ended be bounded perhaps?

Comment: @qbert - I thought so, but I actually don't know the correct translation. What I mean by coherent is that the graph "sticks" together such that there are no "holes" in the graph

Comment: Simply connected maybe? What language are you translating from? Might be worth adding this, there are people from all over the world here

Comment: it must be $$4\sqrt{3}y-13x^2-7y^2-6\sqrt{3}xy-4x\geq 0$$

Comment: Translation problems aside, the "approach" is to find out where you'd be in trouble extracting the square root of a negative number. Everything else will be in the domain. Draw a picture.

Comment: Actually its the inside of an ellipse

Comment: @qbert Good point, I did that now

Answer (score 0):

[image]If you take a pure translation
$$ x = p - \frac{1}{2} \; \; , \; \; y = q + \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \; \; ,  $$
you reach
$$ 13 p^2 + 6 pq \sqrt 3 + 7 q^2 \leq 4 \; \; .  $$
Follow with a pure rotation,
 $$ p =  \frac{u \sqrt 3 - v}{2} \; \; , \; \; q =  \frac{u + v\sqrt 3}{2} \; \; ,  $$
you reach
$$ 4 u^2 + v^2 \leq 1 \; \; .  $$
Which is an ellipse with its interior. Closed, bounded, and connected.

Depends which order you are writing the rotation, anyway the matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} & - \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}
\end{array}
\right)
$$
is orthogonal, top row is sine and cosine of $120^\circ$